# SwiftUI: use Link with onTapGesture

Tags: swiftui

I want to specify a Link in my SwiftUI view, but I also want to register when/if that `Link` was actually tapped or not. What's the best way to do this? I tried adding an `onTapGesture` on the Link (which is a View I believe):

```
Link("Test", destination: URL(string: "testThreePanel://")!)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Testing button link tapped")
                    }
```

But the `onTapGesture` doesn't get invoked on tapping the link.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could try this, works for me, but only on iOS15 / macOS12:

```
// iOS15 / macOS12 only 
Link("Test", destination: URL(string: "https://duckduckgo.com")!)
        .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
            print("---> testing link actioned")
            return .systemAction
        })
```

Comment: I tried this and got an error message: "Key path value type 'WritableKeyPath<EnvironmentValues, OpenURLAction>' cannot be converted to contextual type 'KeyPath<EnvironmentValues, OpenURLAction>'"

Comment: Is this supposed to only work in iOS 15.0 / macOS 12.0? Because I would need to support iOS14 / macOS11 as well.

Comment: yes you are correct, it works on ios 15, macos 12. There was no mention of io14 in the question. I'll delete my answer if it's no use to you.

Comment: Thanks. You can label the original answer with the fact that it's only for iOS15 / macOS12, and I'll mark it as the answer. I don't believe there's another way to do it at this point.

Comment: updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just enable firing both embedded and added gestures simultaneously.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Link("Test", destination: URL(string: "testThreePanel://")!)
            .simultaneousGesture(
                TapGesture()
                    .onEnded { val in
                        print("Testing button link tapped \(val)")
                    }
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 15 it also works if you remove the 'url' parameter, just in case you don't want to use it.

```
Link("Test", destination: URL(string: "https://duckduckgo.com")!)
.environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { _ in
                print("---> testing link actioned")
                return .systemAction
            })
```