# Run code on link click/tap in macOS Widget (SwiftUI)

Tags: macos, swiftui, hyperlink, widgetkit

I've a macOS SwiftUI widget (using WidgetKit) with minimum supported OS version set to 11.  This detail is important as I want to run some code when a link view is clicked/tapped by the user:

```swift
Link("StackOverflow.com", destination: URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com/")!)
  .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
    print("hello, world")
    return .systemAction
  }
)
```

[SwiftUI: use Link with onTapGesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69938011/swiftui-use-link-with-ontapgesture) asserts that this only works on macOS 12+ as [it's a read-only property in macOS 11](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/openurl-openurlaction/).  However, irrespective of the OS version, this doesn't work on *widgets*; it works only on apps.

1. Adding a handler for `onTapGesture` which never gets called
2. Adding a `onTapGesture` for the parent `HStack` which never gets called
3. Posting a notification from link's `onOpenURL` handler and receiving it in HStack's `onReceive` (refer [How to set addObserver in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58818046/how-to-set-addobserver-in-swiftui))
4. Removed the `Link` and made it a `Button` with `action:` set, but handler never seems to get called

in vain.  Any click on the widget dismisses it and opens the main app.

Comment: What do you want to do in that action? I just try to understand possible direction of workaround.

Comment: Add some debug/log code.  As it is, it's terrible to debug widgets on macOS.  Xcode doesn't help either.  Sorry for the bitterness, but that's kinda the answer.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, not so far.