# How to know Link is clicked in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a requirement that when user clicks on a button to make a call, I need to send a request to backend to do something.
I used Link view to do that, the code is quite simple like this:

```
Link(destination: URL(string: "tel:110")!, label: {
                    Text("Call 110")
                })
```

I tried to add modifier of onTapGesture to Text, and this makes the Link not work.
And I also tried to add modifier of onOpenUrl to Link, but it doesn't callback either.

I guess there's a solution to use Text instead of Link, and add modifier onTapGesture to call `UIApplication.shared.open(theUrl)` and then make the remote request.

But I still want to know if there's a way to know the Link is clicked.

Thanks a lot

Comment: have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69938011/swiftui-use-link-with-ontapgesture